# How to set a background-color to element which has the same id with anchor of url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML structure like this:

```
<table id="table-843" cellspacing="0" class="comment">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="43">
            <td class="vote_comment">3</td>
            <td class="content_comment">anything1</td>                          
        </tr>
        <tr id="44">
            <td class="vote_comment">7</td>
            <td class="content_comment">anything2</td>                          
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Also I have a url like this:

```
www.example.com/posts/231#44
```

Now I want to set a orange-background-color to `<tr id="44">` and hide it after 2sec. exactly like stackoverflow. How can I do that? should I use JavaScript for that? or just CSS?

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: @Paulie_D Ok, I will. Thakns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var elem = $(location.hash).css('background-color', '#FC9A24');
setTimeout(function() {
   elem.css({"background-color":"transparent", "transition":"background-color 0.5s ease"});
}, 2000);
```

Comment: @stack yes, url have hash which is the same as id selector.

Comment: Can you please add `animate({'background-color' ...` to your solution? (for hiding)

Comment: @stack To animate color you will need extra plugin.

Comment: Are you sure? I just want to hide the background-color smoothly ..! Also I use jQuery.., that is not enough?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with CSS alone by using the [`target` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Atarget) to select the row and then [animating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation) its `background`. Here's a quick example; click on the links under the table to see it in action:

```css
#table-843 tr:target{
  animation:flash 1s;
}
@keyframes flash{
  0%,50%{
    background:#fc9;
  }
  100%{
    background:#fff;
  }
}
*{color:#000;font-family:arial;}
a{display:block;margin:0 0 5px;}
table{border:1px solid #999;border-spacing:2px;margin:20px 0;}
td{border: 1px solid #ccc;padding:5px;}
```

```html
<table id="table-843" cellspacing="0" class="comment">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="43">
      <td class="vote_comment">3</td>
      <td class="content_comment">anything1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="44">
      <td class="vote_comment">7</td>
      <td class="content_comment">anything2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<a href="#43">Highlight #43</a><a href="#44">Highlight #44</a>
```

Comment: Sounds great ..! Thanks. +1

Comment: You're welcome. Note that you may need to prefix some of the animation properties, depending on which browsers you need to target. See [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) for more infomation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.location.hash` to retrieve value of hash in url.
It will return `#44`, so you will have to trim 1st character.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/rajesh_dixit/pen/yYmPdp#44).

Note: *Kindly check on CodePen.*

#### Code

```js
(function() {
  var id = window.location.hash.substring(1);
  console.log(id);
  document.getElementById(id).className = "orange";

})()
```

```css
.orange{
  background:orange
}
```

```html
<table id="table-843" cellspacing="0" class="comment">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="43">
      <td class="vote_comment">3</td>
      <td class="content_comment">anything1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="44">
      <td class="vote_comment">7</td>
      <td class="content_comment">anything2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Well, I don't see any background color for none of those comments in your fiddle.

Comment: try adding `#44` in URL if its not present